# List object is not callable when using groupby

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to group a list of lists by comparing the first item and while the code runs I get a "List object is not callable error"

Below is all my code for reference

```
import code
from itertools import groupby

stuff = [[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [1, 'c'], [2, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [2, 'c'], [2,'d']]

gb = groupby(stuff, stuff[0])

code.interact(local=locals())
```

**Console**

```
>>> gb
<itertools.groupby object at 0x000000000334C4A8>
>>> for item in gb:
...     print(item)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be? Thanks in advance

Comment: The second argument to `groupby` is a key function not list object.
You probably want something like: `groupby(stuff, key=lambda x: x[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for

```
gb = groupby(stuff, lambda item: item[0])
```

The second argument is a `key` function that is applied to each item and should return the group key. The same principle as with sorting.

Comment: Can also do the concise: `import operator; operator.itemgetter(0)` instead of the lambda

Comment: @JeffTratner: it's certainly different, and can be faster I think, but I'm not sure I'd say that it's really more concise; `itemgetter(0)` is only one character shorter than `lambda x: x[0]`, after all.  (Not counting the import.)  `itemgetter` also isn't very robust, as if you decide you want to do any transformations you're back to needing a function again.